# How to determine the status of a Google BigQuery job using a Service Account?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

We are trying to determine the status of a job on BigQuery using a service account from App Engine.

The following code will determine the status of a job but we need to change it from using the default App Engine credentials to a service account.

```
 credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

 bigquery = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

 request = bigquery.jobs().get(projectId=PROJECT_ID, jobId=JOB_ID)

 result = request.execute(num_retries=2)
```

How would we change this to use a service account to get the status of a BigQuery job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `oauth2` directly, like so:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('./key.json')
```

You can install it by:

```
pip install google-oauth
```

Comment: Cool :)! Forgot to mention, if you are using Standard Environment, now there's the option of using the [second generation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/) of python appengine. There you can install any library you want so you could use official client for connecting to gcp.